# Directory created by C# program thread is locked

Tags: c#, windows

I have this program that creates threads on which i must create queue folders and
check them for files.

Now I noticed my program failed after processing a huge number of files without problems.
I produces a `UnauthorizedAccessException` so I went looking for that folder and it appears
the folder has been locked out totally?!

Could this be my anti-virus blocking access or is it something I must fix on my thread?

[image: Queue]

```
public class worker
{

    public bool Stopping = false;

    private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private List<string> _files;

    #region Feedback

    public event FeedbackHandler Feedback;
    public delegate void FeedbackHandler(object sender, string text);

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    private string _folder;
    public string Folder
    {
        get { return _folder; }
        set { _folder = value; }
    }

    private string _outfolder = Path.Combine(shared.Root, "out");
    public string Outfolder
    {
        get { return _outfolder; }
        set { _outfolder = value; }
    }

    private string _backupfolder = Path.Combine(shared.Root, "backup");
    public string Backupfolder
    {
        get { return _backupfolder; }
        set { _backupfolder = value; }
    }

    private string _filter = "*.*";
    public string Filter
    {
        get { return _filter; }
        set { _filter = value; }
    }

    private SearchOption _subfolders = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
    public bool Subfolders
    {
        get { return (_subfolders == SearchOption.AllDirectories); }
        set { if (value) { _subfolders = SearchOption.AllDirectories; } else { _subfolders = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly; } }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public worker(string Name)
    {
        _name = Name;

        _folder = Path.Combine(shared.Root, "queues");
        _folder = Path.Combine(_folder, Name);

    }

    #endregion

    #region Destructor

    ~worker()
    {

    }

    #endregion

    #region Control

    public void Start()
    {

        Stopping = false;

        Directory.CreateDirectory(_folder);

        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1);
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Start();

        Feedback(this, "[" + _name + "] started!");

    }

    public void Stop()
    {

        Stopping = true;

        Feedback(this, "[" + _name + "] stopped...");

    }

    void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (Stopping)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            _files.Clear();

            return;
        }

        _timer.Stop();

        Process();

        _timer.Start();
    }

    #endregion

    void Process()
    {

        if (Directory.Exists(_folder))
        {

            _files = Directory.GetFiles(_folder, _filter, _subfolders).ToList();

            foreach (string _file in _files.ToArray())
            {

                if (Stopping) { break; }

                document _document = new document(_file);

                _document.Copy(_backupfolder);
                _document.Move(_outfolder);

            }

            _files = new List<string>();

        }

    }

}



public class document
{

    private string _header;

    #region Feedback

    public event FeedbackHandler Feedback;
    public delegate void FeedbackHandler(object sender, string text);

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private string _file;
    public string File
    {
        get { return _file; }
    }

    private job _job;
    public job Job
    {
        get { return _job; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public document(string File)
    {
        _file = File;

        _header = shared.FileOperations.ReadHeader(_file);

        _job = new job(_file, _header);
        _job.ReadHeader();

    }

    #endregion Constructor

    public void Copy(string Folder)
    {
        string _backupfile;

        _backupfile = Path.Combine(Folder,_job.Name);
        _backupfile = Path.Combine(_backupfile,_job.Company);
        _backupfile = Path.Combine(_backupfile, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
        _backupfile = Path.Combine(_backupfile, DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM"));

        Directory.CreateDirectory(_backupfile);

        _backupfile = Path.Combine(_backupfile, Path.GetFileName(_file));

        shared.FileOperations.CopyFile(_file, _backupfile, true);

    }

    public void Move(string Folder)
    {

        string _outfile;

        _outfile = Path.Combine(Folder, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_file));

        shared.FileOperations.MoveFile(_file, _outfile, true);
    }
}



public struct shared
{
    public static string Root
    {
        get
        {
            string _base = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
            return Directory.GetParent(_base).Parent.FullName.ToString();
        }
    }

    public struct Patterns
    {
        public const string Header = @"\^?JOB\s(?<JOB>[a-zA-Z0-9]+[0-9]{3})[D]?(?<ACTION>[JFE]+)(?<COMPANY>[A-Z]{2,2})\s" +
                                        @"(?<EMAIL>-emto=.*)?" +
                                        @"-C(?<COPIES>[0-9]{2,2})\s" +
                                        @"-Z""(?<PRINTER>[A-Z0-9]+)""\s" +
                                        @"(?:\^?PAGE 01|(?<FAX>\^?FAX.*)\s\^?PAGE 01?)";

        public const string Jump = @"\^PAGE\s[0-9]+";

        public const string Pages = @"(\$?PAGE\s)";

        public const string Fax = @"\^?FAX FROM_COMPANY\s""(?<FROM>.*)""\s" +
                                            @"\^?FAX FROM_FAX_NUM\s""(?<FFAX>.*)""\s" +
                                            @"\^?FAX FROM_NAME\s""(?<FNAME>.*)""\s" +
                                            @"\^?FAX TO_FAX_NUM\s""(?<TFAX>.*)""\s" +
                                            @"\^?FAX TO_COMPANY\s""(?<TO>.*)""\s" +
                                            @"\^?FAX TO_NAME\s""(?<TNAME>.*)""\s" +
                                            @"\^?FAX WHO\s""(?<WHO>.*)""\s" +
                                            @"\^?FAX ID\s+(?<ID>.*)";

        public const string Mail = @"-em([^\s=]+)=(""[^""]*""|[^\s]+)";

        public const string Seperator = @"^";

    }

    public struct FileOperations
    {

        // Encoding
        public static Encoding ReadEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
        public static Encoding WriteEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        // Timeouts
        static int Timeout = 1;
        static int FileTimeout = 10000; // 10 seconds/file permitted..

        // Header
        public static string ReadHeader(string SourceFile)
        {
            return ReadHeader(SourceFile, Patterns.Jump);
        }

        public static string ReadHeader(string SourceFile, string Beacon)
        {

            WaitFile(SourceFile);

            string r = null;
            string l = null;

            try
            {
                StreamReader _reader = new StreamReader(SourceFile, ReadEncoding);
                Match _match;

                do
                {

                    l = _reader.ReadLine();
                    r += l + " ";

                    _match = Regex.Match(l, Beacon);

                } while (!_match.Success);

                _reader.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                // todo
                if (Debugger.IsAttached) { throw ex; }

            }

            return r;

        }

        // Read Contents
        public static List<string> ReadFile(string SourceFile)
        {
            return ReadFile(SourceFile, Patterns.Seperator);
        }
        public static List<string> ReadFile(string SourceFile, string Seperator)
        {

            WaitFile(SourceFile);

            List<string> lines = new List<string>();

            try
            {

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(SourceFile, Encoding.GetEncoding(1250));
                string tmp = null;
                string line = null;

                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {

                    line = sr.ReadLine();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line.Substring(0, 1) == Seperator)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp))
                        {
                            lines.Add(tmp);
                        }

                        tmp = line.Replace(Seperator, "^");

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        tmp += Environment.NewLine + line;

                    }

                }

                sr.Close();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp))
                {
                    lines.Add(tmp);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // todo
                if (Debugger.IsAttached) {throw ex;}

            }

            return lines;

        }

        // Write Contents
        public static void WriteFile(string DestinationFile, List<string> Lines)
        {
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllLines(DestinationFile, Lines.ToArray(), WriteEncoding);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // todo
                if (Debugger.IsAttached) { throw ex; }
            }

        }

        public static void WriteFile(string DestinationFile, string Contents)
        {
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText(DestinationFile, Contents);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // todo
                if (Debugger.IsAttached) { throw ex; }
            }
        }

        // Move File
        public static void MoveFile(string SourceFile, string DestinationFile, bool Overwrite)
        {
            WaitFile(SourceFile);

            try
            {
                string _count = null;
                string _destination = Path.GetDirectoryName(DestinationFile);
                string _file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(DestinationFile);
                string _extension = Path.GetExtension(DestinationFile);

                string[] _files = Directory.GetFiles(_destination, _file + "*");

                if (_files.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (Overwrite)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x <= _files.Length - 1; x++)
                        {
                            File.Delete(_files[x]);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _count = "_" + (_files.Length - 1).ToString("D4");
                    }

                }

                DestinationFile = Path.Combine(_destination, _file + _count + _extension);

                File.Move(SourceFile, DestinationFile);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (Debugger.IsAttached) { throw ex; }
            }

        }

        public static void CopyFile(string SourceFile, string DestinationFile, bool Overwrite)
        {
            WaitFile(SourceFile);

            try
            {
                string _count = null;
                string _destination = Path.GetDirectoryName(DestinationFile);
                string _file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(DestinationFile);
                string _extension = Path.GetExtension(DestinationFile);

                string[] _files = Directory.GetFiles(_destination, _file + "*");

                if (_files.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (Overwrite)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x <= _files.Length - 1; x++)
                        {
                            File.Delete(_files[x]);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _count = "_" + (_files.Length - 1).ToString("D4");
                    }

                }

                DestinationFile = Path.Combine(_destination, _file + _count + _extension);

                File.Copy(SourceFile, DestinationFile);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (Debugger.IsAttached) { throw ex; }
            }
        }

        // Delete File
        public static void DeleteFile(string SourceFile)
        {
            WaitFile(SourceFile);

            try
            {
                File.Delete(SourceFile);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // todo
                if (Debugger.IsAttached) { throw ex; }
            }

        }

        // Check File
        static void WaitFile(string SourceFile)
        {
            Timeout = 1;

            while (!File.Exists(SourceFile))
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Timeout);

                Timeout++;

                if (Timeout == FileTimeout)
                {
                    // todo
                    if (Debugger.IsAttached) { throw new Exception("Timout exceeded!"); }
                }
            }

            Timeout = 1;

            while (!IsFileReady(SourceFile))
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Timeout);

                Timeout++;

                if (Timeout == FileTimeout)
                {
                    // todo
                    if (Debugger.IsAttached) { throw new Exception("Timout exceeded!"); }
                }

            }
        }
        static bool IsFileReady(String SourceFile)
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream inputStream = File.Open(SourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                {
                    if (inputStream.Length > 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }

    public struct Functions
    {

        public static string CleanXML(string Text)
        {

            Text = Text.Replace(@"&", @"&amp;");
            Text = Text.Replace(@"<", @"&lt;");
            Text = Text.Replace(@">", @"&gt;");
            Text = Text.Replace(@"""", @"&quot;");
            Text = Text.Replace(@"'", @"&apos;");

            return Text;
        }
    }
}



void Work(string Name)
    {
        _worker = _workers.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name == Name);

        if (_worker == null)
        {

            _worker = new worker(Name);
            _worker.Feedback+=new worker.FeedbackHandler(Feedback);

            _worker.Folder = Path.Combine(_queuefolder, Name);
            _worker.Outfolder = _outfolder;
            _worker.Backupfolder = _backupfolder;

            _workers.Add(_worker);

            Thread _thread = new Thread(_worker.Start);

            _thread.Start();
            _thread.Join();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should post your **code**...what do you do inside your threads? If you just create folders then nothing is locked but if you keep a file open (or you create a FileSystemWatcher) then they'll be locked until you dispose that resource.

Comment: Could you provide the code that is related to the creation of the folder(s)/file(s)? My first guess is that it has to do with your thread.

Comment: Updated question with code...

Comment: Note that even if my program quits the folder exists only until I reboot.

Comment: Sorry for uploading code in non-structural manner.  

Flow is like following:  
  
- queue created and started.  
- queue creates collections with documents.  
- documents are outputted to their respective queue folder.  
- workers created on seperate thread based on document queue.

Comment: Your app will execute its code under the user account which it's configured with, and will therefore create a folder under that account when called to do so. My first question would be to know what user account is the owner of that folder and what user account is running your app. If you are running the app with an admin account, then you have found your issue .. And several other implied security problems.

Comment: Hi Michael, non-IIS but winform environment (DLL).

Comment: Who is the current owner of the folder when it is locked? What is the the permission schema of the dir (inherited or not)

Comment: I created the folder and my program runs with default (logged on) credentials. I even fail to take ownership of that folder.

Comment: Is your account an admin account? I know it's a dumb question as u probably are an admin but its worth checking.

Comment: There are so many things that might go wrong in your code. For starters, look at this line: `_timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1);`. You basically make timer rise a delegate every millisecond. Which creates racing between `_timer.Stop();` method and Elapsed event. You might want to do both: inrease the interval and make your eventhadler thread safe. Or you can replace timer with a simple loop to svae yourself a trouble

Comment: admin, domain admin, not sure if admin @ home but yeah...

Comment: Is it still like that after a reboot? I am trying to figure out if maybe the problem is a stuck resource lock in the kernel instead of a permissions issue.

Comment: you mean something like

`while(true){}`  I'd prefer to start at `1` and increase. Does that imply thread-safe? I'm new to threading...

Comment: No, reboot fixes the permission settings...

Comment: Nik, I'll start by increasing my interval of both queue and worker (thread) from 1 to 100ms. I can't seem to reproduce the problem... :(
What do you mean by making my eventhandler thread safe???

Comment: Also forgot to mention Explorer.exe crashed 5mins ago during my program.... lol

Comment: Then it's not a permissions issue which would point to a resource lock issue because rebooting does not change permissions but rebooting will clear the resource lock. Do you have multiple threads running to create the same directory? You really should make sure that the folder does not already exists before you try to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify what i meant:

```
//worker class   
private volatile bool _stopping;
private Thread _thread;

public void Start()
{

    _stopping = false;

    Directory.CreateDirectory(_folder);

    _thread = new Thread(Process);
    _thread.Start();

    Feedback(this, "[" + _name + "] started!");

}

public void Stop()
{

    _stopping = true;
    _thread.Join();

    Feedback(this, "[" + _name + "] stopped...");

}

private void Process()
{
     while(!_stopping)
     {
         ......
         Thread.Sleep(100);
     }
}
```

Because the way you are using timers... It's wrong. And while its interesting to know, why windows locks the folder, you should start from doing some refactoring. It might actually solve your problem along the way.

Comment: Thanks Nik, I'll review my code and see if I can make it more efficient and less error-prone... Why am I using timers, you ask?
I've tried using Filesystemwatcher but I could not implement it in
a proper way. (see other people having issues with this object)